# CSS: right : 0px ; property is not working

Tags: html, css

The code is as follows:

```css
.form-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid rgb(68, 240, 0);
  background-image: radial-gradient(rgb(252, 252, 252), #ffffff);
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 40px;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.close-button {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0px;
  left: auto;
  border: 1px solid rgb(240, 0, 0);
  width: 40px;
}

.form-header {
  border: 1px solid rgb(232, 0, 240);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.form-header h3 {
  display: inline;
}

.form-outline {
  border: 1px solid rgb(237, 250, 235);
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 5px 30px;
}

.form-field {
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.form-field input {
  outline: none;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 2px solid rgb(179, 177, 177);
  border-radius: 6px;
  background-color: rgba(227, 247, 250, 0.918);
}

.form-field small {
  display: block;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
  <div class="close-button"><i class="far fa-times-circle "></i></div>
  <div class="form-header">
    <!-- <div style="border: 2px solid aqua;"></div> -->
    <h3> Lets talk!</h3>

  </div>

  <form class="form-outline">
    <div class="form-field">
      <label class="field-title">Name </label><br>
      <input type="text" id="" value="" placeholder="Enter your name."> <br>
      <small class="error-message">Error message</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
      <label class="field-title">Phone </label><br>
      <input type="text" id="" value="" placeholder="Enter your phone number."> <br>
      <small class="error-message">Error message</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
      <label class="field-title">Organization </label><br>
      <input type="text" id="" value="" placeholder="Enter your organization's name."><br>
      <small class="error-message">Error message</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
      <label class="field-title">Address </label><br>
      <input type="text" id="" value="" placeholder="Enter your address."> <br>
      <small class="error-message">Error message</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-field">
      <label class="field-title">Email </label><br>
      <input type="text" id="" value="" placeholder="Enter your email."> <br>
      <small class="error-message">Error message</small>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[The result looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvQzi.png)

I want to move the "close button" to the right side sticking to the green border of form-wrapper div. The right property is not working. I don't know if it is a silly mistake or lack of knowledge. Any help or direction would be appreciated.
I tested the right property using another html file and it is working perfectly. But I could not move this close button to right.

Comment: I've just tested your code and im not getting the same result. It's working as you want

Comment: Btw I get your result by setting the close button position to relative, check if it is set to absolute in the chrome dev tools. Maybe there is another style interfering with it

Comment: `div.close-button
{ 
    position:absolute;
    right:0px; 
    left:auto;
    border:1px solid rgb(240, 0, 0); 
    width: 40px;
    height:40px;
}`
I used div.close-button and it worked for me. I have no idea why specificity was an issue. Position property is used relative for parents.

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your close-button class. it worked for me.

```
.close-button {
direction: rtl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is fine and should work propely. Maybe your styles without `right: 0px;` is cached by browser. Try to open your project in new private / incognito tab. It prevents browser to read cached styled.